# difference between Immediately-Invoked Function and jQuery Immediately-Invoked Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have read that `(function(){})();` is called immediately and doesn't need to be called.
and `$(function());` is also immediately called.

- are they both and have same functionality ?
- does the Immediately-Invoked Function loaded after the document is completely loaded ?
- what is the actual functionality of `$(function());` ?
- does `$(function());` after the document is completely loaded ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(function(){});
```

isn't immediately called : it is called when the DOM is ready. It's a shortcut for

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: What is it equivalent to in vanilla JavaScript? OnLoad()?

Comment: @thomas The best equivalent of ready would be [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState) but most often, if you don't need the resources to be loaded, the simplest solution is to call your code from a script element at the end of the body (when the elements have already been defined).

Answer (score 1):

`(function () {})()` is an anonymous function that is immediately called.

`$(function () {});` is jQuery shorthand for `$(document).ready(function () {});`

Comment: What is it equivalent to in vanilla JavaScript? OnLoad()?